# Update através da diferença de valor por id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Estou tentando realizar um update através deste select, onde eu vejo quais são os dados diferentes da tabela pen_cadastro, mas ao tentar realizar um update, apresenta erros:

**[MYSQL]**

**UPDATE:**

```
begin transaction
UPDATE pen_cadastro as CADAS
left OUTER JOIN novosusuarios 
ON novosusuarios.id <> CADAS.id 
set
CADAS.id = novosusuarios.id
group by novosusuarios.id
```

**SELECT(Isto está funcionando):**

```
SELECT novosusuarios.*
FROM pen_cadastro 
left OUTER JOIN novosusuarios
ON novosusuarios.id <> pen_cadastro.id 
group by novosusuarios.id
```

Ou seja, preciso fazer um update de acordo com a diferença de ID de uma tabela para outra, se não houver os novosUsuarios na tabela pen_cadastro então ele irá inserir os valores nos campos set que eu apontar.

Comment: A dúvida é sobre MySQL ou sobre SQL Server? Há duas tags marcadas; poderia verificar?

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que usar uma referencia de sua tabela quando for envolver mais de uma tabela ,ou seja, usar um join.

Tente assim.

```
update CADAS
set CADAS.id = novosusuarios.id
FROM pen_cadastro as CADAS
left OUTER JOIN novosusuarios as novosusuarios
ON novosusuarios.id <> CADAS.id 
group by novosusuarios.id
```

Comment: Ae que está o problema ela não possui referência.

Comment: quis dizer renomear pen_cadastro as CADAS ... (CADAS)